# [Rails]update_without_password doesn't update user info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I executed following code

```
  @user = User.find(current_user.id)

successfully_updated = if needs_password?(@user, params)
  @user.update_with_password(params[:user])
else
  # remove the virtual current_password attribute update_without_password
  # doesn't know how to ignore it
  params[:user].delete(:current_password)
  @user.update_without_password(params[:user])
end

if successfully_updated
  set_flash_message :notice, :updated
  # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case his password changed
  sign_in @user, :bypass => true
  redirect_to after_update_path_for(@user)
else
  render "edit"
end
```

but update_without_password give `false` and database is rollbacked.
Do I have to do something for update_without_password?

Answer (score 3):

I just went through my own issues with this. The following code should work as advertised (as found on the wiki page for Devise).

```
def update    
  @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  successfully_updated = if needs_password?(@user, params)
    @user.update_with_password(params[:user])
  else
    params[:user].delete(:current_password)   
    @user.update_without_password(params[:user])
  end

  if successfully_updated
    set_flash_message :notice, :updated
    sign_in @user, :bypass => true
    redirect_to after_update_path_for(@user)
  else
    render "edit"
  end
end
```

Make sure you also define the private method for 'needs_password?'

```
def needs_password?(user, params)
  (params[:user].has_key?(:email) && user.email != params[:user][:email]) 
     || !params[:user][:password].blank?
end
```

My issue was that I had removed the "email" field from the form in the 'edit.html.erb' file, so the 'needs_password?' method kept returning true since user.email was never equal to nil. To fix the issue, I added in a check `params[:user].has_key?(:email)` to see if 'email' exists in the hash.

FWIW, the 'update_without_password' pretty much works the same way as 'update_with_password' except that it strips out the 'password' and 'password_confirmation' parameters before calling 'update_attributes' on the object, so you shouldn't have to do anything more. Try looking upstream a bit and see if you really are calling 'update_without_password'.